# Fell head over heels on/to (someone)

Tags: prepositions

Let's say you and your family are going on holiday(you, wife, a child). Then, a moment occured where you have to teach your child how to handle money well. After that, your child was amazed at what you did.

> Then you said:''This is the reason why your mother fell head over heels **on/to** me''(lol)

My question is, as for that example given, which is the ***correct preposition?***

Comment: We can also fall for a ruse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct preposition is **"FOR** me"